# float not working on text and image elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navbar using HTML and CSS but my CSS `float: right` and `float: left` statements aren't working, everything is still on the right side.

```css
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-item {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 8 px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" width=50 height=50>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Download</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't have li without a parent list element. Also, nav-item may need to have display: inline-block; for your float to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned in a comment you need to wrap your list items in a `<ul>` tag. This is both the correct syntax and will allow you to have the entire list of links go to the right.

I also added `justify-content: space-between` to tell flex to align items left/right, and `display: inline-block` to the nav-item for them to display in a single line, rather than stacked as block level elements.

```css
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-item {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" width=50 height=50>
            <ul>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Download</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost good, please don't use float, instead you can use `display: flex` and use `margin-left: auto` to move things to the left.

```css
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-item {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" width=50 height=50>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Download</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @JordanBaron yes, but that's for your padding, Improve your padding and margin, but flex should fix your positioning problem

Comment: @JordanBaron I update your margin and padding, try the edited css, should work now, you have a space on the padding of the `nav-item`

Comment: I check the snippet again, and is working, your code should have something else affecting the CSS causing problem, run the snippet on my answer and watch yourself.